# Laravel Routing Does not Work

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I am new in LARAVEL framework and I want to run a controller with just function of view a page

```
class TestController extends BaseController {

    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('hai');
    }
}
```

I set the routing in routes.php file as given below

```
Route::get('test','TestController@index');
```

I tried to run in mozilla with

```
localhost/laravel/public/test
```

but it shows

```
Not Found
The requested URL /laravel/public/test was not found on this server.
```

is there any problem in my .htaccess page   ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any body please help me.

Comment: You can try this route `Route::get('test', ['uses' => 'TestController@index']);`

Comment: Whoops, looks like something went wrong

Comment: Did you check your previous question's answer (quite similar) ? Also make `debug => true` in `app/config/app.php` file so you'll get an informative error message (You emailed me for help).

Comment: Do you have create `hai.blade.php`?

Comment: hey....working as welll. thank you....

Comment: Are you miss `hai.blade.php` view?

Comment: no. i dont create hai.blade.php

Comment: only a hai.php file.....     what is the hai.blade.php  ?

Answer (score 13):

I'm assuming that you are on Ubuntu machine. To make it work, at first, enable the rewrite module by executing following command in the terminal

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Second, find "apache2.conf" file in your system, mine is located in

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

In this file, find the following snippets of code:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Change "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All". Save the file and restart the apache server by executing following command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This should solve the issue. Cheers

Comment: It works! For installation path other than `/var/www/` find  `<Directory />` snippet.

Comment: Saved my damn life! Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

Precondition: you will know that you have htaccess working, if when you first installed laravel and went to `localhost/laravel/public/`, you'd see the laravel logo.

The route is:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

Regarding Your route: you don't need to explicitly state the function (@index) in the route. Laravel has a default path it follows based on the HTTP request type. Check [here](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers) (under the heading *Actions Handled By Resource Controller*) for more details on that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply I refer you not modifying .htaccess file. From http://tisuchi.com/easy-way-handle-routing-laravel/:

> Static Page Handling
>
> Handling static page in laravel is one of the easiest way to handle
>   route. Open app/routes.php file and deleted everything from that.
>   Assume that, we are try to route into our following pages- home
>   (example.com), about (example.com/about), contact
>   (example.com/contact).  To do so, just write following code in your
>   routes.php file-
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Static page code
>  */
>
> Route::get('/', function(){
>     return View::make('home');
> });
>
> # For example.com/about
> Route::get('about', function(){
>     return View::make('about');
> });
>
>
> /**
>  * Naming Route for static Page
>  */
> # For example.com/contact
> Route::get('contatct', array('as' => 'contact', function(){
>  return View::make('contact');
> }));
> ```

If you are really new in Laravel, highly recommend to look into following 2 tutorials-

- http://freshwebdev.com/best-laravel-tutorial-beginners.html
- http://tisuchi.com/easy-way-handle-routing-laravel/

Ofcourse, don't forget to take a look into official page of laravel.com. 
Hope, it will work for you.

Have fun...